# How to install a lower install version of visual studio Installer project forcefully,without manually removing ,while installing it?

Tags: visual-studio

I have an installer project setup from version, 1.0.0 ,1.0.1 and 1.0.2.Each having different changes I needed for my project.When I install them in order,they upgrade properly and get installed nicely.But I have a need where I need to go back from 1.0.2 to 1.0.1,but the setup project won't let me install it since it already has a newer version installed.And one of the ways I can get around it, is to manually uninstall it and run it.But I don't want the end user to do that and just run whatever setup he wants and it gets install removing previous versions.  Can anyone suggest me a workaround for this or how to handle this situation?